# Firebase FCM Remote Notification didReceiveRemoteNotification not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a simple app working with Firebase Cloud Messaging. I implemented all instruction of FCM for messaging but when I testing my physical device when in background, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function not triggered.

When I take my app in background, there's an log message:

> Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 7 (0x7), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug. The UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods are working well even when you used not in background mode.

Here is the implementation of it.

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let info = userInfo as? [String:Any]{

            print("info > ", info)

        }

      completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Also firebase setup:

```
override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }


    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {granted, options in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
          })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        return true
    }
```

What I want is using `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method because of testing background mode of the physical phone navigation diagram.

Here is the code for these functions.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        switch application.applicationState{
        case .inactive:
            // active
        case .background:
            // background
        case .active:
            // active

        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        print("--")
    }
```

I've searched along the Stack Overflow and the situation of "Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier" is about bug of iOS 13.2 but my phone is currently running in 13.3 version. Background mode is active for remote notifications too.
so I haven't found the problem even in developer.apple forum.

Why the function is not triggered when I click notification when the app is in background mode?

Comment: FYI on Stack Overflow, backtick quotes are used for marking bits of code, not for general emphasis. I edited the question to correct it.

Comment: @DougStevenson, hey Doug, I checked your edit, thanks for it I'll think about it for newer questions.